# error says vulkan queue waiting on semaphore that has no way to be signaled (actually will be signaled)

Tags: graphics, synchronization, semaphore, vulkan, raytracing

I have read these two similar questions:

1. [Vulkan queue waiting on semaphore that has no way to be signaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149998/vulkan-queue-waiting-on-semaphore-that-has-no-way-to-be-signaled)
2. [vkQueuePresentKHR validation bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/1423)

The first one is caused by signaling semaphore A and waiting on semaphore B; The second one is caused by present before submit. However, my case is quite different. When the program runs, the validation layer will throw error:

```
--> Validation Error: [ VUID-vkQueuePresentKHR-pWaitSemaphores-03268 ]
Object 0: handle = 0x14e37396870, name = queueGCT, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE;
Object 1: handle = 0x2b424a0000000034, name = swapchainWrittenSemaphore:1, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SEMAPHORE; |
MessageID = 0x251f8f7a |
vkQueuePresentKHR: Queue VkQueue 0x14e37396870[queueGCT] is waiting on
pWaitSemaphores[0] (VkSemaphore 0x2b424a0000000034[swapchainWrittenSemaphore:1]) that has no way to be signaled.
```

According to the message, the error is most likely caused by a semaphore that will never be signaled. However, this is weird.In my case, the swapchain creates 3 entries and has 3 somaphore pairs (readSemaphore[0,1,2] and writeSemaphore[0,1,2]). My program is like:

```cpp
// Main loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(...)) {
    // ...
    prepareFrame();
    // create command buffer and record commands ...
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmdBuf, &beginInfo);
    // -- ray tracing...
    // -- post processing...
    vkEndCommandBuffer(cmdBuf);
    submitFrame();
}
```

In the prepareFrame(), the swapchain `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` and will signal `readSemaphore[cur_loop % 3]` when preparing is done.

In the submitFrame(), the program first `vkQueueSubmit` which waits on `readSemaphore[cur_loop % 3]` and will signal `writeSemaphore[cur_loop %3]` when queue is done. Then the program `vkQueuePresentKHR` which waits on `writeSemaphore[cur_loop %3]`. The code can be found in [nvpro_core](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/nvpro_core)'s swapchain_vk.h/cpp and appbase_vk.h/cpp.

The error will only be trigered When the loop goes through the 2nd (or 3rd) time and the triger point is `submitFrame()::present()::vkQueuePresentKHR()`. It is weird because the 1st loop and 2nd/3rd loop do the same thing but there is no problem with the 1st loop. I debugged the code and found that the waitSemaphore `writtenSemphore[1]`[enter image description here](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/nvpro_core/issues/37) in vkQueuePresentKHR() should have been signaled by vkQueueSubmit() in submitFrame().

In visual studio debugger, `semaphoreWrite = 0x2b424a0000000034` and `written = 0x2b424a0000000034`. The image can referred [here](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/nvpro_core/issues/37):

`vkQueueSubmit` signals `semaphoreWrite` and `vkQueuePresentKHR` waits on `written`. They are the same semaphore.

The strangest thing is that this bug seems to be related to my raytracing shader code. When I comment the raytracing procedure in main loop, the program runs fine. If the raytracing procedure is preserved, simple shader code like generating a uv coordinate at the output image will not cause problem, while computing hit distance will.

```c
// writing uv coordinate, works fine
// ---------------------------------
// ray generation
void main()
{
  const ivec2 resolution = imageSize(image);
  const ivec2 pixel = ivec2(gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy);
  if((pixel.x >= resolution.x) || (pixel.y >= resolution.y))
  {
    return;
  }
  vec4 color = vec4(pixel.x / float(resolution.x),
                    pixel.y / float(resolution.y),
                    0.0, 0.0);
  imageStore(image, pixel, color);
}
// close hit
void main() {}
```

```c
// writing depth, works fine
// ---------------------------------
// ray generation
traceRayEXT(topLevelAS,     // acceleration structure
              rayFlags,       // rayFlags
              0xFF,           // cullMask
              0,              // sbtRecordOffset
              0,              // sbtRecordStride
              0,              // missIndex
              origin.xyz,     // ray origin
              tMin,           // ray min range
              direction.xyz,  // ray direction
              tMax,           // ray max range
              0               // payload (location = 0)
  );

  imageStore(image, ivec2(gl_LaunchIDEXT.xy), vec4(payload.radiance, 1.0));
// close hit
void main() {
    payload.radiance = vec3(gl_HitTEXT);
}
```

However, made a small adjustment, the error will occur:

```c
// close hit
void main() {
    payload.radiance = vec3(gl_HitTEXT/100.0);
    // or any other operation to gl_HitTEXT
    // or
    // float x = gl_HitTEXT * 2;
    // payload.radiance = vec3(x);
}
```

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Some code [here](https://gist.github.com/f1shel/3707292d6b6683c5eec3a4a12d6f4781).

Comment: Solved. Finally, I found that only ray generation shader was added to the shader group when creating shader binding table.

Comment: You should post the above comment as an answer and press the big checkmark to accept it so future people with this problem will see it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Finally, I found that only ray generation shader was added to the shader group when creating shader binding table. That is, close hit shader and ray miss shader were missing.